# No type or protocol named 'GADNativeAdLoaderDelegate'

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, google-mobile-ads

I am working on iOS project which in build on both Objective-C and Swift language. I have successfully Added GoogleMobileAds in Objective-C code but when I add in swift file I am getting this error.

> “No type or protocol named 'GADNativeAdLoaderDelegate”.

I searched all the documentation but I failed to resolve this error. Please help me to resolve this.

[image]

GADNativeAdLoaderDelegate Already added in Objective-C code and it's working fine.